Display country based prices within 3D-configurator
i hope you can support me with some problems i faced while trying to introduce country based prices into my rubens configurator.
I extending the options within the "pricing"-parameter for other countries. But at the end it always shows the default prices.
Currently i'm displaying only default prices for my country using the "pricing" parameter in the configuration script:
"pricing": [{ "region": "default", "currency": "EUR", "price": "price= 0; price Logic goes here"}]
Based on the documentation here:
https://docs.roomle.com/rubens/content-creation/scripting-resources/200_130_pricing
i now tried extending it like the following:
"pricing": [{ "region": "fr", "currency": "EUR", "price": "price = '' price logic for fr;" }, { "region": "nl", "currency": "EUR", "price": "price = '' price logic for nl; } ],
However it still shows the prices of the default region.
Am i missing something here?

Be aware that you are using the Scripted  Price Service. This is a Legacy feature and is not recommended.
In order to use prices from a different countries, you would need to use the regular Roomle Price Service where you set prices for article numbers via a CSV Upload.
In the CSV, different Prices for different countries can be set for the same article number as the docu shows. When you have everyhing in place, you can change the displayed price for different countries by using the overrideCountry=STRING flag in the URL.
Here you can finde more to the topic of localisation.
https://docs.roomle.com/rubens/rubens-products/rubens-configurator/customisation/localization

Thanks for your reply! Yes, i already know that this is a legacy feature. However, this is was i got when i took over this project. My hope was now, that i can just extend the current implementation. I already play around with the regular one. But one question is still left for me: Do you know how to turn it  on or off for testing cases? I uploaded a csv for testing purposes and since then the logic seems to use this one. But no button or anything else to turn it off again?

If you don´t want to use the Price service, just set the URL flag to false. But the price services use different URL flags.
The "regular" Price service uses usePriceService=false
while the Legacy one uses useRoomlePrice=false

Thanks for the hint! That already helps a lot!
